# Create access token using identity framework with exist mvc 5 project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, access-token

I want to generate access token by using identity framework to communicate with my android app. Type of my project just default MVC project not API project .
**Anyone can give me some examples?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on this website

http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/